# Challenging Multithreading Problems

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there some resource for challenging multi-threading problems? Would like to pose these to interviewees if possible. Tired of asking the same wait-notify questions that everyone gets right these days, but can't visualise a real scenario where multi-threading was employed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you can't visualize a real scenario for multithreading, why do you want to hire people who know about it? I mean, grab a real scenario from the software you or your company produces.

Comment: I meant to say that most people just parrot the stuff they read in java books and cannot come up with any real scenarios 'themselves'.

Comment: So you ask you candidates questions that are irrelevant to the job description you are hiring for, and want to make them even harder.

Comment: @Ehrann Mehdan: huh? most people claim to have worked on multi-threaded apps for the type of jobs I interview them for.

Comment: so ask them to describe a (Possible real) scenario for using multithreading, what the involved problems are and how they should be solved.

Comment: If you're having to evaluate candidates on something you don't know yourself then you're not the person to be evaluating those people.

Comment: @blowdart: wow very insightful comment indeed. Im asking people for resources on multi-threading problems to pose to interviewees, if you dont have anything to add to it, you don't need to comment here either.

Comment: He is adding to it, just not in a way you want to. Your question is valid, however so is the direction of these comments.

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that concurrent programming is a difficult topic.  If you (the interviewer) are not fully on top of it, it will be difficult for you to tell if the interviewee knows their stuff.  It is very easy to come up with solutions to concurrency problems that have subtle flaws.  Conversely, it is unfair on candidates<sup>1</sup> if you reject them because you think their answers are wrong *when they are actually correct*.

---

<sup>1 - and bad for your organisation.  If the candidate actually knows more about multi-threading than you, then you arguably *need* to employ him.  Other factors being equal, of course.</sup>

Answer (score 10):

[Java Concurrency In Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/). I like to know if candidate understand data race, CAS, Michael Scott Queue and other concurrent data structures and how concurrent thread safety is important with growing number of cores.

Answer (score 1):

As multithreading is *hard* (as others have pointed out) I would suggest having this in an actual programming session where the potential employee is given a programming problem preferrably based on something that has actually happened along with one of your experienced programmers so you can actually SEE how the problem was attempted solved, and the experienced programmer can evaluate what happened.

Must not be too complex, but complex enough that your expereinced programmer get enough information.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to have fun with the poor sap, ask him about Dekker's Algorithm (and Peterson's variation thereof).  If you're feeling nasty, ask him if he has ever used either one on real multiprocessor hardware.

If you feel extra-nasty, ask him to show you a technique suitable for lock-free true concurrent single-reader single-writer unidirectional communications, between two processors with shared memory, in which the only atomic operations are single-word reads and writes.  There is no read-modify-write instruction, on either side, and the processor architectures need not be the same.  (Yes, such a technique exists.)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't ask too specific/detailed questions. But the above mentioned book 'Concurrency in practice' is a good helper. Just go there chapter-wise and read out the pin-points, e.g.:

- Explain difference between mutable/immutable
- What does it mean to share data in concurrency setup
- What problems do you solve with concurrency
- etc.

Answer (score 1):

First you 
try to get the real scenario 
of it, and then ask job seekers.
For this you should pose a questions like what is real scenario for multithreading? 
Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I got one in a interview recently.  Get the candidate to write a Servlet that implements an accurate in memory hit counter indexed by URL (to serve a javascript style hit counter on a number of web page).  Try it for yourself, it's not as easy as it sounds.  The solution is a cut down implementation of the Memoizer pattern from [Concurrency in Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com).

Comment: That sounds like a StackOverflow question on its own. What are the issues? Could you not use a ConcurrentHashMap and some AtomicLongs? (I'm assuming not clustered).

Comment: That's basically it.  If you implement it, it looks similar to the Memoizer, but without the FutureTask.  However it's surprisingly tricky to do in the midst of an interview.